# Delete part of a string in SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, trim, cut

I have a table with a field with this kind of entries:

```
"text text text"
"text text - Cap. 125"
"text - Cap. 1"
```

I need to cut `" - Cap. (Number)"`.

As you can see in some cases there's no `"Cap."` and in other cases the number has more than 1 digit.

I tried to use `REPLACE()` and `TRIM()`, but `REPLACE()` only works for `" - cap."` but not for the numbers; and `TRIM()` cut a specific number of characters.

Also, I think I need something like `WHERE field LIKE '% - CAP.%'` to verify that I'm changing the right field, because not all the fields need to be changed.

Any suggestions?

Comment: just text.. "world cup - Cap. 205"

Comment: Is "Cap nnn" always at the end of the text?

Comment: in some cases yes. in others there's no " - cap number"..

Comment: btw, check that the number can be 1 digit 2 or 3

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT CASE
         WHEN myField RLIKE ' - Cap\\. [[:digit:]]{1,3}$' THEN
           LEFT(myField, 1
             + CHAR_LENGTH(myField)
             - CHAR_LENGTH(' - Cap. ')
             - LOCATE(REVERSE(' - Cap. '), REVERSE(myField))
           )
         ELSE myField
       END
FROM   myTable
```

See it on [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/ad184/3/0).

Comment: Great! now can you please verify if this is the right way to update the fields?
========
UPDATE rollooriginal SET CASE
         WHEN RO_Titulo RLIKE ' - Cap\\. [[:digit:]]+$' THEN
           LEFT(
             RO_Titulo, 1
               + LENGTH(RO_Titulo)
               - LENGTH(' - Cap. ')
               - LOCATE(REVERSE(' - Cap. '), REVERSE(RO_Titulo))
           )
         ELSE RO_Titulo
       END
WHERE RO_Titulo LIKE '%Cap. %';
========

Comment: You're almost there: `UPDATE rollooriginal SET RO_Titulo = LEFT(RO_Titulo, 1 + CHAR_LENGTH(RO_Titulo) - CHAR_LENGTH(' - Cap. ') - LOCATE(REVERSE(' - Cap. '), REVERSE(RO_Titulo))) WHERE RO_Titulo RLIKE ' - Cap\\. [[:digit:]]{1,3}$';` should do it.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT SUBSTRING_INDEX(column_name, 'Cap', 1) FROM table ; // for left
SELECT SUBSTRING_INDEX(column_name, 'Cap', -1) FROM table; // for right
```

Comment: Question is tagged [tag:mysql].

Comment: What if `text` contains `'Cap'`?  Also, in the event that `Cap` is not present (as in the first example), both `left` and `right` return the full string.

Comment: #1548 - Cannot load from mysql.proc. The table is probably corrupted